# I want to add these two select lists with each other

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select name,value from  (  
    select name,value from 
    (
      select 'WHB' name,count(*) value from bld_comp_prep where bld_comp_code ='WHB' and comp_code =:a_bld_user_comp and nvl(status,'S')='S' and nvl(delete_flag,'N') ='N'
    union all
      select 'RBC' name,count(*) value from bld_comp_prep where bld_comp_code ='RBC' and comp_code =:a_bld_user_comp and nvl(status,'S')='S' and nvl(delete_flag,'N') ='N'
    union all
      select 'FFP' name,count(*) value from bld_comp_prep where bld_comp_code ='FFP' and comp_code =:a_bld_user_comp and nvl(status,'S')='S' and nvl(delete_flag,'N') ='N'
    union all
      select 'PLC' name,count(*) value from bld_comp_prep where bld_comp_code ='PLC' and comp_code =:a_bld_user_comp and nvl(status,'S')='S' and nvl(delete_flag,'N') ='N'
    union all
      select 'CRY' name,count(*) value from bld_comp_prep where bld_comp_code ='CRY' and comp_code =:a_bld_user_comp and nvl(status,'S')='S' and nvl(delete_flag,'N') ='N'
    union all
      select 'GRC' name,count(*) value from bld_comp_prep where bld_comp_code ='GRC' and comp_code =:a_bld_user_comp and nvl(status,'S')='S' and nvl(delete_flag,'N') ='N'
    ) 
left JOIN ( 
select name,value from(
  select  'WHB' name, count(*) value from bld_issue_dtl dtl,bld_issue_hdr hdr,bld_comp_prep prep where prep.bld_comp_code ='WHB' and hdr.issue_code =dtl.issue_code and hdr.comp_code =dtl.comp_code and dtl.comp_bag_code =prep.comp_bag_code and dtl.comp_code =prep.comp_code and TO_DATE(hdr.issue_date,'DD-MON-YY') =TO_DATE(:P29_STOCK_DATE,'DD-MON-YY')
union all
  select  'RBC' name, count(*) value from bld_issue_dtl dtl,bld_issue_hdr hdr,bld_comp_prep prep where prep.bld_comp_code ='RBC' and hdr.issue_code =dtl.issue_code and hdr.comp_code =dtl.comp_code and dtl.comp_bag_code =prep.comp_bag_code and dtl.comp_code =prep.comp_code and TO_DATE(hdr.issue_date,'DD-MON-YY') =TO_DATE(:P29_STOCK_DATE,'DD-MON-YY')
union all
  select  'FFP' name, count(*) value from bld_issue_dtl dtl,bld_issue_hdr hdr,bld_comp_prep prep where prep.bld_comp_code ='FFP' and hdr.issue_code =dtl.issue_code and hdr.comp_code =dtl.comp_code and dtl.comp_bag_code =prep.comp_bag_code and dtl.comp_code =prep.comp_code and TO_DATE(hdr.issue_date,'DD-MON-YY') =TO_DATE(:P29_STOCK_DATE,'DD-MON-YY')
union all
  select  'PLC' name, count(*) value from bld_issue_dtl dtl,bld_issue_hdr hdr,bld_comp_prep prep where prep.bld_comp_code ='PLC' and hdr.issue_code =dtl.issue_code and hdr.comp_code =dtl.comp_code and dtl.comp_bag_code =prep.comp_bag_code and dtl.comp_code =prep.comp_code and TO_DATE(hdr.issue_date,'DD-MON-YY') =TO_DATE(:P29_STOCK_DATE,'DD-MON-YY')
union all
  select  'CRY' name, count(*) value from bld_issue_dtl dtl,bld_issue_hdr hdr,bld_comp_prep prep where prep.bld_comp_code ='CRY' and hdr.issue_code =dtl.issue_code and hdr.comp_code =dtl.comp_code and dtl.comp_bag_code =prep.comp_bag_code and dtl.comp_code =prep.comp_code and TO_DATE(hdr.issue_date,'DD-MON-YY') =TO_DATE(:P29_STOCK_DATE,'DD-MON-YY')
union all
  select  'GRC' name, count(*) value from bld_issue_dtl dtl,bld_issue_hdr hdr,bld_comp_prep prep where prep.bld_comp_code ='GRC' and hdr.issue_code =dtl.issue_code and hdr.comp_code =dtl.comp_code and dtl.comp_bag_code =prep.comp_bag_code and dtl.comp_code =prep.comp_code and TO_DATE(hdr.issue_date,'DD-MON-YY') =TO_DATE(:P29_STOCK_DATE,'DD-MON-YY')
)));
```

Comment: This is not a question. Questions end with the character `?`. And I have no idea what you mean by "add these two select lists with each other".

Comment: The question is not clear. You may want to have a look at [mcve] to build an example and clarify your question. As is, I believe the question will be closed soon.

Comment: Two things I notice: 1) your inner queries can just be a single query with GROUP BY, 2) you should use `JOIN` instead of SELECT ... FROM x, y WHERE ...  After those are fixed, see if the proper join to connect the two tables isn't clearer.

Comment: @Gary_W I looked at the pre-edit, holy cow. Good edit, saved me from a heart attack. :P

Comment: @Gary_W sorry, It was more about that you gave a great edit than anything else. I'm currently checking it out.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner queries can just be written as

```
  select bld_comp_code name, count(*) value 
  from bld_comp_prep 
  where comp_code =: a_bld_user_comp 
    and nvl(status,'S')='S' 
    and nvl(delete_flag,'N') ='N'
    and bld_comp_code IN ('WHB', 'RBC', 'FFP', 'PLC', 'CRY')
  group by bld_comp_code
```

and

```
select  prep.bld_comp_code name, count(*) value 
from bld_issue_dtl dtl,
     bld_issue_hdr hdr,
     bld_comp_prep prep 
where hdr.issue_code = dtl.issue_code 
  and hdr.comp_code = dtl.comp_code 
  and dtl.comp_bag_code = prep.comp_bag_code 
  and dtl.comp_code = prep.comp_code 
  and TO_DATE(hdr.issue_date,'DD-MON-YY') = TO_DATE(:P29_STOCK_DATE,'DD-MON-YY')
  and prep.bld_comp_code IN ('WHB', 'RBC', 'FFP', 'PLC', 'CRY')
group by prep.bld_comp_code
```

which can be written with the preferred JOIN syntax as:

```
select  prep.bld_comp_code name, count(*) value 
from bld_issue_dtl dtl
INNER JOIN bld_issue_hdr hdr
        ON hdr.issue_code = dtl.issue_code 
       and hdr.comp_code = dtl.comp_code 
INNER JOIN bld_comp_prep prep 
        ON dtl.comp_bag_code = prep.comp_bag_code 
       and dtl.comp_code = prep.comp_code 
where TO_DATE(hdr.issue_date,'DD-MON-YY') = TO_DATE(:P29_STOCK_DATE,'DD-MON-YY')
  and prep.bld_comp_code IN ('WHB', 'RBC', 'FFP', 'PLC', 'CRY')
group by prep.bld_comp_code
```

however it's not clear how you're intending to JOIN the two sets or what the expected result is.

Comment: @Aleksej Good catch - forgot to add the column back before the alias.